# Application is not opening after clicking on Notification

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) CONTEXT
                            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,                                    "New Messege", System.currentTimeMillis());                         

// Hide the notification after its selected

notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

// Opening application on notification select

Intent intent = new Intent(CONTEXT, Welcome.class);

//intent.putExtra("payload", payload);


PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(CONTEXT, 0,intent, 0);

notification.setLatestEventInfo(CONTEXT, "Message","message", pendingIntent);

notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

My problem is that, when I click on notification in Notification Center, it dose not start my app. Basically, after clicking on my notification nothing happens!I have tried lots of solution but nothing happen.

I have an another problem when the app is running(not in background) it also shows the notification in the notification bar.please guide me. 
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do :

```
notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

Take a look at this brilliant tutorial, explaining a lot of this on notifications :
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNotifications/article.html

Comment: basically m developing a chat app. but when user on the other side send  msg it again and again shows in the running aap(app is not running in the background).

Comment: This is the normal behaviour to show the notification in the status bar even if the app is not running in background. You can handle yourself this event though, to detect if the app is in foreground or background to show or not the notification.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code snippnet helps you:

```
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void shownotification(Context context)
    {
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("My notification")
                .setContentText("Hello World!")
               // .setDeleteIntent(getDeleteIntent())
               // .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(), 0))
                .setOngoing(true);

        // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MYDEMOACTIVITY.class);
            // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
        // started Activity.
        // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
        // your application to the Home screen.
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MYDEMOACTIVITY.class);
        // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                    0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
        mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

**Explaination:** Here mid is my app's notification id `eg:final int mId = 0;` and MYDEMOACTIVITY.class is my another activity which I want to start after clicking the notification.